# DBI connection to SQL Server (and Sybase 12.5) does not return greek characters

Tags: sql-server, r, rstudio, sybase

I tried connecting to a Sybase db, using the DBI package, but queries do not return greek characters correctly.

Same for connections to SQL server. Here is an example of a `dbConnect` command:

```
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = "Driver={SQL Server};server=ATLAS;database=master;trusted_connection=true")
```

I had no problem when I used RODBC (with the same System DSN)

[image]

Table contents:

[image]

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Greek_Greece.1253  LC_CTYPE=Greek_Greece.1253    LC_MONETARY=Greek_Greece.1253 LC_NUMERIC=C                 
[5] LC_TIME=Greek_Greece.1253    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] odbc_1.1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bit_1.1-12     compiler_3.4.1 hms_0.3        DBI_0.7        tools_3.4.1    tibble_1.3.4   yaml_2.1.14    Rcpp_0.12.12   bit64_0.9-7   
[10] blob_1.1.0     rlang_0.1.2
```

Comment: Could it be that you don't have a matching language pack in your perl installation? What does it return when connecting through DBI?

Comment: I do not have a perl installation.
_> dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "PIND_ERGOSE", CharSet = "cp1253")
<OdbcConnection> dbo@omiros
  Database: ERGOSE
  SQL Server Version: 12.50.0000_

Comment: @GeorgeDontas My sense is the problem with your CharSet.

See https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/440/

nb. I had a similar problem a few years back on Windows and had to change the Charset. Why? Cp1252 does not define the values between 128 and 160 so they get converted to ?.

I hope the above helps.

Comment: Old ODBC drivers don't support unicode encodings (i.e., nvarchar). Try using a newer version of the SNAC,`Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try setting the `encoding` parameter in `dbConnect()`. From `?odbc::dbConnect`

> encoding: The text encoding used on the Database. If the database is
>             the same as your local encoding set to ‘""’. See
>             ‘iconvlist()’ for a complete list of available encodings on
>             your system. Note strings are always returned ‘UTF-8’
>             encoded.